# lxml.etree Invalid Predicate: "./tbody/tr[position() = 1]"

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

The XPath `'./tbody/tr[position() = 1]'` is accepted by Firefox's XPath engine, but it's being rejected on lxml 4.5.0 (libxml2 2.9.10; Python 3.8.10; Ubuntu 20.04.5).

```
  …
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1532, in lxml.etree._Element.find
  File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 323, in lxml._elementpath.find
  File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 312, in lxml._elementpath.iterfind
  File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 295, in lxml._elementpath._build_path_iterator
  File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 237, in lxml._elementpath.prepare_predicate
SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

Is the [`position()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) function not supported by lxml? If not, what alternatives are there?

Comment: `tbody` may not exists in html source and might be added by the browser. `./table/tr[..]` should work in that case

Comment: @LMC I believe `invalid predicate` isn't thrown if the predicate is valid and the element you're trying to find merely doesn't exist.

Comment: `>>> tree.xpath('./tbody/tr[position() = 1]')
[]` with 4.3.3 lxml version. What's the context node?

Comment: @LMC The context node is an `<Element table at 0x…>`

Comment: `t = tree.xpath('//table') t[1].xpath('./tbody/tr[position() = 1]')
[<Element tr at 0x7fe685a4a4f8>]`

Comment: btw, this works `t[0].find('./tbody/tr[1]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>   File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1532, in lxml.etree._Element.find
> ```

> ### [ElementPath](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elementpath)
>
> … advanced features like value comparison and functions are not available.

For the *particular* use-case in the OP, `.find('./tbody/tr[1]')` will work.

If you end up needing more advanced queries, use `.xpath` instead:

> ### [XPath](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath)
>
> lxml.etree supports the simple path syntax of the find, findall and findtext methods …. As an lxml specific extension, these classes also provide an `xpath()` method that supports expressions in the complete XPath syntax ….
>
> There are also specialized XPath evaluator classes that are more efficient for frequent evaluation: `XPath` and `XPathEvaluator`. See the performance comparison to learn when to use which. Their semantics when used on Elements and ElementTrees are the same as for the xpath() method described here.
>
> #### Note
>
> The `.find*()` methods are usually *faster* than the full-blown XPath support. They also support incremental tree processing through the `.iterfind()` method, whereas XPath always collects all results before returning them. They are therefore recommended over XPath for both speed and memory reasons, whenever there is no need for highly selective XPath queries.